# Creating a grid in in Swing (Netbeans)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I want to create a grid (possibly resizable) for a game where when the specifies a box in the grid and clicks a button, the box is filled with some color. However, I am not sure how to do this especially the grid part. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GridLayout` (for equal size component) or `GridBagLayout` where you may add components  (say `JLabel` or `JPanel`) and set border for each added component.

Sample:

```
class GridPane extends JPanel
{
   public GridPane(int row,int col)
    {
         setLayout(new GridLayout(row,col));
         setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1,1,1,1));

         for (int i =1; i<=(row*col); i++)
          {
             JPanel pan = new JPanel();
             pan.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30,30));
             pan.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY));
             add(pan);
           } 

    } 
}
```